# Being on the same wavelength

Tags: waves, terminology, everyday-life, resonance, wavelength

The usage of physics terminology outside of technically minded people seems limited. That's why I am curious about the phrase *being on the same wavelength* which as far as I understand is generally understood (and also exists in at least the German language, that's why I ask here and not at English language stackexchange).

- What is the origin of this phrase?
- Does it refer originally to interference or resonance or...?
- What other physics/maths/engineering terms have made it into everyday English language?

Comment: This seems a little off topic for the Physics Stackexchange and probably would do better on the English Language & Usage exchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it originate from early radio transmissions, a clue only, I only really know that for two radios to communicate they must be tuned to the same wavelength.